# how to change color of censor tick and truncate KM curve if number at risk is < 5 using lifelines library?

Tags: python, plot, lifelines, risk-analysis

Is it possible to change the colour of the censor tag in lifelines?
The code-chunk that I used was

```
kmf.plot_survival_function(
    show_censors=True,
    censor_styles={'ms': 5, 'marker': '|'},
    at_risk_counts=True,
    ci_show=False
)
```

And how to truncate when the number at risk falls below a certain limit?

Comment: That depends entirely on what library this is.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention. It's lifelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying class that is used in `lifelines` for drawing the markers is [`matplotlib.lines.Line2D`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html), and `censor_styles` is passed to that class as `kwargs` when you call `plot_survival_function`.

You can use the property `markeredgecolor` (or `mec`) with a color code and it'll change the marker color.

Here's an example based on the KMF sample code from `lifelines`'s documentation.

```
from lifelines import KaplanMeierFitter
from lifelines.datasets import load_waltons
waltons = load_waltons()

kmf = KaplanMeierFitter(label="waltons_data")
kmf.fit(waltons['T'], waltons['E'])

kmf.plot_survival_function(
    show_censors=True,
    censor_styles={'ms': 20, 'marker': '|', 'markeredgecolor': '#ff0000'}, 
    color='#abc3f0',
    at_risk_counts=True,
    ci_show=True
)
```

And the resulting image with my red markers:

[image: sample with red markers]

Comment: @SaheliSaha sorry, didn't notice that part. If you just want to truncate your y-axis, you could add the keyword argument `ylim=(low_range)` - I _think_ that might be what you want? Like `kmf.plot_survival_function(..., ylim=(5,))`